# Base64 data in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have file and process with awk tool.

```
awk -F "|" '{print $3 "|" $7 "|" $1 "|" $2}' animals.csv | grep cats >> data.txt
```

How can i make $3 to encode base64 format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this :

```
awk -F "|" '
    {
        "echo "$3" | base64" | getline x
        print x, $7, $1, $2
    }
' OFS='|' animals.csv | grep cats >> data.txt
```

the awk's `getline` read a variable from a system command.

Comment: Consider using `echo -n` to avoid newline in base64

Comment: @user3447705: First try to figure out how your version of `base64` works, then modify as expected.

Comment: in mac os not work, in ubuntu ok. but have another error: sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Answer (score 2):

Pure shell script.

```
IFS="|"
while read A B C D E F G X
do
  base64=$(echo $C|base64)
  echo "$base64|$G|$A|$B"
done < animals.csv | grep cats >> data.txt
```

Comment: Indeed it's easier to implement with shell.